# Kitematic not showing any Images/Containers

Tags: docker, kitematic

I have pulled three images from docker hub using docker.I have listed those three images below

```
suju@suju-VirtualBox:~$ sudo docker images -a
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mysql               latest              71b5c7e10f9b        11 days ago         477MB
hello-world         latest              fce289e99eb9        4 weeks ago         1.84kB
java                latest              d23bdf5b1b1b        2 years ago         643MB
```

And i installed kitematic 0.17.6 for purpose of Managing Docker container
but when i open kitematic, it doent show any container, its just shows a white window without any options except exit